# Enviar valor desde un botón en Spring-boot Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Estoy intentando programar un menú de una cafetería, en el cual al presionar el botón de algún ítem este se grabe y me retorne un mensaje del registro recién grabado. El problema que tengo es que al presionar el botón de grabar, no graba solo dicho menú sino que todos los disponibles.

[image: Menu]

En la siguiente imagen se puede notar que cuando me retorna el menú grabado, no retorno solo 1 sino que todo el listado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Considero que esto es por utilizar el form-action, pero intenté de otras formas y no logro hacer que funcione correctamente.

Si alguien puede indicarme como hacerlo correctamente, muy agradecido.

Mi plantilla es la siguiente:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../static/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.css}"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--  <p th:text="'Hello, ' + ${name} + '!'"></p>
        <p th:text="'Hello, ' + ${sum} + '!'"></p>
        <div>TODO write content</div>-->
        
        <div class="container">
        <form action="/addmenu">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <caption>Menu</caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Descripción</th>
                    <th>Agregar</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="prodId" value="1"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="prodName" value="Desayuno 1"/></td>
                    <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">+</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="prodId" value="2"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="prodName" value="Desayuno 2"/></td>
                    <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">+</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="prodId" value="3"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="prodName" value="Desayuno 3"/></td>
                    <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">+</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="prodId" value="4"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="prodName" value="Almuerzo 1"/></td>
                    <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">+</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="prodId" value="5"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="prodName" value="Almuerzo 2"/></td>
                    <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">+</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="prodId" value="6"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="prodName" value="Cena 1"/></td>
                    <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">+</button></td>
                </tr>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </form>
        
        <p th:text="'Item grabado, ' + ${item} + '!'"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Mi controlador es el siguiente:

```
package gt.com.antiguaburguer.ASIIHT1.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@Controller
public class IndexController {
    @GetMapping("/api")
    public String Saludo(@RequestParam String nombre, Model mimodelo){
        //return "Hola Sr." + nombre;
        mimodelo.addAttribute("name",nombre);
        return "Index"; //nombre de la plantilla
    }   
    
    @GetMapping("/ejemplosuma")
    public String Suma(@RequestParam int numero1, @RequestParam int numero2, Model mimodelo) {
        mimodelo.addAttribute("sum", numero1+numero2);
        return "Index"; //nombre de la plantilla
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/showmenu")
    public String product(Model model) {
        //model.addAttribute("products", productRepository.findAll());
        return "Menu";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/addmenu")
    public String save(@RequestParam String prodName, @RequestParam String prodId, Model mimodelo) {
        mimodelo.addAttribute("item", prodName);
    //return "saludo" + product.getId();
        return "Menu";
    }
}
```

Comment: Todos los botones **+** realizan la misma acción: envían **todo** el formulario a tu servidor. Puesto que todos los *inputs* del formulario se llaman igual (`prodId` y `prodName`), el navegador agrupa los valores por nombre: crea una lista con los valores de `prodId`, y otra con la lista de valores de `prodName`. No tengo claro lo que intentas hacer, así que no sé solución darte.

Comment: @PabloLozano muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Lo que deseo hacer es que si solo presiona el botón del primer menú, solo ese menu sea enviado al controlador. Así abajo muestro que menú fue seleccionado, no todos.

Comment: Se me ocurren varias cosas: Usar AJAX es una opción, pero si quieres recargar la página entera de nuevo una opción sería crear un form para cada grupo de dos inputs y un botón submit, teniendo todos los form el mismo `action`.